# Find the continuous solution to the initial value problem (second order)

Tags: initial-value-problems

$y''+4y = f(x)$

$f(x)=\cases{\sin x,  &$0\le x\le 2\pi$\\   
     x, &$x>2\pi$}$

with $y(0)=0 , y'(0)=0$

My attempt is ...
general solution $r^2 = -4 , r = \pm 2i$

$y(x) = c_1e^{2i} + c_2e^{-2i} = c_1(\cos(2t) +i\sin(2t))+c_2\cos(-2t) +i\sin(-2t))$

substitution with $0$ and it gets strange..
$y(x=0) = 0, y'(x=0) = 0$

$c1, c2 = 0...?$

I searched this ..[Find the continuous solution to the initial value problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2419975/find-the-continuous-solution-to-the-initial-value-problem)
So, I went directly to integrate equation...and it seems doesn't right.

1. List item

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Simplest way is using Laplace transform.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution must be $$y(x)=C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)+\frac{\sin(x)}{3}$$ Check it!

Comment: ...how come? TT I don't know how to proceed to get this.